# How to sort the data taking into account the subtraction of numbers until the right number is obtained in R

Tags: r, sorting, for-loop

I have a complicated problem related to the sorting of the data.

Introduction to the issue. Below are two tables that include data in annual granularity for the same units.

The first table refers to the load per year for each unit.

**Table 1. Load per year**

| Year | Unit A | Unit B | Unit C | Unit D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 5000 | 4000 | 3000 | 2000 |
| 2024 | 5000 | 4000 | 3000 | 2000 |
| 2025 | 5000 | 4000 | 3000 | 0 |
| 2026 | 0 | 4000 | 3000 | 0 |
| 2027 | 0 | 0 | 3000 | 0 |

The second table refers to the marginal price per year for each unit.

**Table 2. Marginal cost per year**

| Year | Unit A | Unit B | Unit C | Unit D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 120 | 240 | 170 | 150 |
| 2024 | 140 | 250 | 180 | 175 |
| 2025 | 160 | 270 | 190 | 0 |
| 2026 | 0 | 300 | 200 | 0 |
| 2027 | 0 | 0 | 215 | 0 |

I would like the units in the tables above to be sorted in such a way that the matching starts from the lowest marginal cost (table 2) and continues until the total load (table 1) reaches the assumed level in table 3 (column number 3 in table 3). Below I have presented the data in how I would like the solution to look after sorting.

The expected solution:
**Table 3. Sorted units**

| Year | Hour | Required load |  |  |  |  | Missing load (Required load - sum units load) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 3 | 10000 | Unit A | Unit D | **Unit C** |  | 0 |
| 2023 | 4 | 13500 | Unit A | Unit D | Unit C | **Unit B** | 1000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2025 | 5 | 8000 | Unit A | Unit C |  |  | 0 |
| 2025 | 6 | 18000 | Unit A | Unit C | **Unit B** |  | 6000 |

Even better and more accurate would be to present  a marginal cost instead of unit names, because I am interested in which unit and at what marginal cost closes the pile (which is the most expensive unit) like:

| Year | Hour | Required load |  |  |  |  | Missing load (Required load - sum units load) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 3 | 10000 | 120 | 150 | **170** |  | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2025 | 5 | 8000 | 160 | **190** |  |  | 0 |

I tried different ways but unfortunately I did not find the right way to sort this way.

Many thanks for any suggestions and solutions.

Comment: May it be that table 3 is missing?

Comment: @AndreWildberg The post has been edited. Now table 3 has been marked.

Comment: Ok, but now its unclear where *Hour* comes from. Also, whats the assumed level?

Comment: Table 3 is just a snippet of the huge date table. The _Year_ and _Hour_ are from 2023 to 2050, meaning there are 8760 hours for each year. And for each hour there is a different value from column C. We can assume that the date table has years and hours from 2023 to 2050 along with _Required load_ and the rest of the columns are to be sorted.

Comment: *Column C is, of course, column number 3 in the table 3 (_Required load_)

Comment: The first thing I would do is reformat and join the tables to give you long-format data with columns for Year, Unit, Load and Marginal cost as a single data set, which will make the ensuing manipulations easier.

Comment: That's a good point! Let's assume that the data table will be reformatted and prepared in this way. How to sort so that it simultaneously sorts out the cheapest cost units and counts the required load?

Comment: `group_by(Year) %>% arrange(Marginal_cost) %>% mutuate(totLoad = cumsum(Load))` off the top of my head (untested) - then mutuate a boolean column to see if totLoad exceeds required load for that year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

Tab1 <- tribble(
~Year,  ~UnitA, ~UnitB, ~UnitC, ~UnitD,
2023,   5000,   4000,   3000,   2000,
2024,   5000,   4000,   3000,   2000,
2025,   5000,   4000,   3000,   0,
2026,   0,  4000,   3000,   0,
2027,   0,  0,  3000,   0)

Tab2 <- tribble(
  ~Year,    ~UnitA, ~UnitB, ~UnitC, ~UnitD,
  2023, 120,    240,    170,    150,
  2024, 140,    250,    180,    175,
  2025, 160,    270,    190,    0,
  2026, 0,  300,    200,    0,
  2027, 0,  0,  215,    0)

Tab3 <- tribble(
  ~Year,    ~Hour,  ~Req_load,
  2023, 3,  10000,
  2023, 4,  13500,
  2025, 5,  8000,
  2025, 6,  18000,
)

consolidatedTab <- Tab1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Year), names_to = "Unit", names_prefix = "Unit", values_to = "load") %>%
  left_join(Tab2 %>%
              pivot_longer(cols = -c(Year), names_to = "Unit", names_prefix = "Unit", values_to = "marg")
            ) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  arrange(marg, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(totLoad = cumsum(load))

SummaryTab <- Tab3 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(missingLoad = ifelse(Req_load - max(consolidatedTab[consolidatedTab$Year == Year,]$totLoad) <= 0,
         0,
         Req_load - max(consolidatedTab[consolidatedTab$Year == Year,]$totLoad)
         ),
         finalUnit = ifelse(missingLoad >0, "N/A", first(consolidatedTab[consolidatedTab$Year == Year & consolidatedTab$totLoad > Req_load,]$Unit)),
         finalunitprice = ifelse(missingLoad >0, 0, first(consolidatedTab[consolidatedTab$Year == Year & consolidatedTab$totLoad > Req_load,]$marg))
         )
```

My best attempt, apologies for lack of explanation but I have to run!

gives:

```
>head(consolidatedTab)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Groups:   Year [2]
   Year Unit   load  marg totLoad
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1  2023 A      5000   120    5000
2  2023 D      2000   150    7000
3  2023 C      3000   170   10000
4  2023 B      4000   240   14000
5  2024 A      5000   140    5000
6  2024 D      2000   175    7000
>
```

and

```
>
# A tibble: 4 × 6
# Rowwise: 

       Year  Hour Req_load missingLoad finalUnit finalunitprice
      <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
    1  2023     3    10000           0 B                    240
    2  2023     4    13500           0 B                    240
    3  2025     5     8000           0 B                    270
    4  2025     6    18000        6000 N/A                    0
```