# How to create a data set that, for each hour, matches the individual elements entering the dataset until a condition has been reached in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, datatable, dataset

I am having trouble creating a solution, whose elements are listed below

Below is a list that includes units sorted by increasing `Marginal_cost`. The last column `Cumulated_Power` counts the power of the `Units` collected in each year. The topic that described the solution presented in the list:
[How to sort the data taking into account the subtraction of numbers until the right number is obtained in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75109217/how-to-sort-the-data-taking-into-account-the-subtraction-of-numbers-until-the-ri)

```
head(Tab_consolidated)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Year [1]
   Year Units         Power Marginal_cost Cumulated_Power
  <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>
1  2023 El_WK_Mol_B1    200           150             200
2  2023 El_WK_Mol_B2    150           200             350
3  2023 El_WK_Rab_B1    300           220             650
4  2024 El_WK_Mol_B2    150           200             200
5  2024 El_WK_Bag_B6    200           250             400
6  2024 El_WK_Bag_B7    330           270             730
```

Below is a table that highlights the `Missing_load` needed to be filled in by the `Units` from `Tab_consolidated` in each hour of the year.

```
> head(Tab_missing_load)
    Year Hour_day Hour_year Missing_load
   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1:  2023        1         1      442.017
2:  2023        2         2      401.548
3:  2023        3         3      375.848
4:  2023        4         4      319.509
5:  2023        5         5      318.953
6:  2023        6         6      141.473
```

I have a problem with a solution that would present the `Units` which enter the system every hour of the year (according to the cheapest `Units` from the `Tab_consolidated`) to fill the `Missing_load`. An example solution, is presented below.

```
> head(Example_solution)
    Year Hour_day Hour_year Missing_load 1_Unit       2_Unit       3_Unit
   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>
1:  2023        1         1      442.017 El_WK_Mol_B1 El_WK_Mol_B2 El_WK_Rab_B1
2:  2023        2         2      401.548 El_WK_Mol_B1 El_WK_Mol_B2 El_WK_Rab_B1
3:  2023        3         3      375.848 El_WK_Mol_B1 El_WK_Mol_B2 El_WK_Rab_B1
4:  2023        4         4      319.509 El_WK_Mol_B1 El_WK_Mol_B2 N/A
5:  2023        5         5      318.953 El_WK_Mol_B1 El_WK_Mol_B2 N/A
6:  2023        6         6      141.473 El_WK_Mol_B1 N/A          N/A
```

I tried various solutions but to absolutely no success. Currently I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Many thanks for any suggestions and solutions.

Comment: Just to ensure that I understand the task correctly, the first 3 units are used because `442.017` is greater than 350 and smaller than 650 (cumulated power column in `Tab_consolidated`) - and if so, why does the last row contains only `El_WK_Mol_B1` shouldn't the missing load be < 150 then?

Comment: @JKupzig I confirm the first question. As for the second question, I corrected in the post and now it should be proper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this helper function to capture the units that should be returned per row, and then use `dcast()` to pivot the result wide:

```
library(data.table)

f <- \(ml,y, cons) cons[Year==y, .SD[1:min(which(Cumulated_Power>ml)), .(Year,Units)]]

setDT(Tab_missing_load)
setDT(Tab_consolidated)

dcast(
  Tab_missing_load[, f(Missing_load,Year,Tab_consolidated), .I][,id:=paste0(rowid(I), "_Unit")],
  Year+I~id, value.var="Units",
)
```

Output:

```
    Year     I       1_Unit       2_Unit       3_Unit
   <int> <int>       <char>       <char>       <char>
1:  2023     1 El_WK_Mol_B1 El_WK_Mol_B2 El_WK_Rab_B1
2:  2023     2 El_WK_Mol_B1 El_WK_Mol_B2 El_WK_Rab_B1
3:  2023     3 El_WK_Mol_B1 El_WK_Mol_B2 El_WK_Rab_B1
4:  2023     4 El_WK_Mol_B1 El_WK_Mol_B2         <NA>
5:  2023     5 El_WK_Mol_B1 El_WK_Mol_B2         <NA>
6:  2023     6 El_WK_Mol_B1         <NA>         <NA>
```

Comment: I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong but I'm getting a message: ```Error: unexpected input in "f <- \"```
Truly I don't quite understand the notation: ```\(ml,y, cons)```

Comment: that is just shorthand for `f<-function(ml,y,cons)`. Since R version 4.1, you may use `\(x)` in place of `function(x)`.  If you are using a version of R prior to that, change to `function(ml,y,cons)`

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought you meant. I have one more question. Despite the identical mapping, I still get errors: ```Error in drop && !has.j : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'``` I wonder if this is related to the version of R. In this case, should I write ```Tab_missing_load$Missing_load``` instead of ```Missing_load```? I ask because the Missing_load notation is not identified by R. Through this problem, I have difficulty identifying ex. from where ```Year``` is taken to the function. Sorry for the questions but I am a beginner.

Comment: I'm not sure.. Perhaps make sure both of your frames are of class data.table?  `setDT(Tab_missing_load)` and `setDT(Tab_consolidated)`??  In your original post, it appears as though Tab_consolidated might be a `tibble`, and `Tab_missing_load` might be a `data.table`.. I've updated the code in my solution to ensure this

Comment: Thank you for the prompt. I apologize for not specifying what shape each DT is. ```Tab_consolidated``` has a ```nrow``` of 3612, while ```Tab_missing_load``` is much larger and has over 240k nrows. Do you have any idea what to do in such a case when we are dealing with unevenly shaped DTs? The error that appears: ```Error in .prepareFastSubset(isub = isub, x = x, enclos = parent.frame(), : 
RHS of == is length 245280 which is not 1 or nrow (3612). For robustness, no recycling is allowed (other than of length 1 RHS).``` Thank you for your help!